# Datatables button onclick doesn't work on Phone mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I´ve a `Jquery DataTables` with 2 buttons and when I click a button in **web mode** everything is ok, I can take the tr data:

[image]

```
     dataTableCierreEfectivo.on('click', 'a[name="edit"]', function() {

            $(fromCierreCajaId).trigger("reset");

            var cierreDeEfectivo = dataTableCierreEfectivo.row($(this).parents('tr')).data()
            console.log(cierreDeEfectivo)
//....
```

**click console log**:
[image]

But when I change to **Phone mode** the data is **undefined**:

[image]

**click console log**:
[image]

Can you tell me why is this happening and how to solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First define the callback function you used for the click event outside of it, something like this:

```
function onclick () {/* Your code */}
```

Then check for the click event like you did before:

```
dataTableCierreEfectivo.on("click", onclick);
```

Then also check if the element was touched:

```
dataTableCierreEfectivo.on("tap", onclick);
```

Let me know if it worked

Comment: @JoseLuis I updated the answer with an example, let me know if it works

Comment: No problem thank for your time, I think tap doesn´t work because im using phone mode in Chrome.